# How to link TextBox data and DataGridView and save it in the MS Access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to make a simple information system. I've tried many codes and I think this is the easiest but it won't save the data. Please point out what I need to do. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code (for the save button):

```
If Len(Trim(txtStudentID.Text)) = 0 then
MessageBox.Show ("Please input data",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error)
txtStudentID.Focus()
Exit Sub
End If

Try
GeneralInformationBindingSource.EndEdit()
GeneralInformationTableAdapter.Update(PayrollDatabaseSet.GeneralInformation)
MessageBox.Show (" Data Saved")

Catch ex As Exception
MessageBox.Show ("Error while Saving Data")

End Try
```

Comment: You call `Fill` on your table adapter to populate a `DataTable` from the database.  You bind that `DataTable` to a `BindingSource`.  You bind that `BindingSource` to one or more controls, including a `DataGridView` and one or more `TextBoxes`.  You add, edit or delete rows as required.  You then call `Update` on your table adapter to save the changes back tot he database.

Comment: If you want a simple system, why use VB.net instead of just VBA within Access?

Comment: used this code for the add button                            GeneralInformationBindingSource.Addnew()

Comment: and this for the save button  .........                            Try                                  GeneralInformationBindingSource.EndEdit()         GeneralInformationTableAdapter.Update(InformationDatabaseDataset.GeneralInformation)             MessageBox.Show("data saved")         catch ex as Exception    MessageBox.show("error")      End Try

Comment: it has been saved in the datagridview while it was running but when i stopped the program, the datas saved were gone in the datagridview and not saved in the database